# Qlik/SQL Server

Tags: sql, qliksense

Long time reader first time poster.

I need some help in returning a corresponding value when a particular value appears.

Example, I want to return the spot A and the value associated with that position. In the first row, that would be 1, second row 3, and third row 1.

```
+-----------+-----------+
| Column A  | Column B  |
+-----------+-----------+
| A;B;C;D;E | 1;2;3;4;5 |
| B;A;C;D;E | 2;3;4;5;1 |
| D;C;E;A;B | 5;2;3;1;4 |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Could you please explain your question better "corresponding value when a particular value appears" this part is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SubField](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense/September2020/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm) function to split both column values. Using `SubField` function (without the `field_no` parameter) creates row for each value.

For example: if we have `A;B;C;D` as value in `MyField` field and we use `SubField(MyField, ';')`. As a result Qlik will create 4 rows:

```
MyField
-------
A
B
C
D
```

So if we use `SubField` on both `ColumnA` and `ColumnB` fields (and keep an index between the new rows) we can create new "flat" table that contains the link between both column split values

Reloading the script below will result in two tables: `Data` and `Flatten`. `Data` is the "raw" data and `Flatten` is the result one

[image: Table Viewer]

Have a look at `Value` and `Index` columns from `Flatten` table. They are the result of using `SubField` on `ColumnA` and `ColumnB`

[image: Flatten table]

```
// Load the sample data
// preceeding load to add ID to each row
Data:
Load
  ColumnA, 
  ColumnB,
  RowNo()  as RowId
;
Load * inline [
ColumnA, ColumnB
A;B;C;D;E, 1;2;3;4;5
B;A;C;D;E, 2;3;4;5;1
D;C;E;A;B, 5;2;3;1;4
];

// Passing RowId across just in case if we want to link back 
// to the Data table
Flatten_Temp:
// Preceding load to add ID (ValueId) for each value in ColumnA
// this ID will be used to join back to the values in ColumnB
Load
  RowId,
  ColumnASplit as Value,
  RowNo()      as ValueId
;
// Using SubField function to create row for each value in ColumnA
Load
  RowId,
  SubField(ColumnA, ';') as ColumnASplit
Resident
  Data
;

JOIN

// Preceding load to add ID (ValueId) for each value in ColumnB
Load
  RowId,
  ColumnBSplit as Index,
  RowNo()      as ValueId
;
// Using SubField function to create row for each value in ColumnB
Load
  RowId,
  SubField(ColumnB, ';') as ColumnBSplit
Resident
  Data
;

NoConcatenate

// Load only 'A' values from the table above
Flatten:
Load
  *
Resident
  Flatten_Temp
Where
  Value = 'A'
;

Drop Table Flatten_Temp;
```

Update: Script updated to return only values for `A`

Comment: hi Stefan, it isn't exactly returning what I am hoping for. I only want the value that corresponds to A for each returned, not all the other values as well (B, C, D etc).

Comment: Updated the script to load resident from the final table and filter the result only for `A`